# how to retrieve specific fields for Object using REST api?

Tags: rest

I know **describe** gives me a list of all the fields available for the specific Object.What if i want to retrieve a subset of the available fields.And I want to do this via REST api?
The reason being is,since I am mapping data from sf to some other application I donot want useless fields which are not required in the mapping.This would affect my performance and useless bandwidth consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no option to filter fields in standard describe REST API. If you can not (or do not want to)filter fields at client end then you will have write your own custom Rest API which return selected fields.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST